# How to get MVC3 to give out less information on errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http, rest, web-config

By default, an MVC3 application gives out a LOT of information for 404's, invalid verbs,  route not found, etc. It has this extremely verbose error page.

***How can we change this behavior***, so that the client still gets the 404's and whatever else, but without this sort of thing being returned?
(***ESPECIALLY*** that stuff at the bottom, which displays our private framework information, class names, etc.)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The resource cannot be found.</title>
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
            <br><br>

            <b> Requested URL: </b>/Foo<br><br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.225

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[HttpException]: A public action method &#39;Index&#39; was not found on controller &#39;MySystem.Api.Rest.Controllers.MyController&#39;.
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->
```

Comment: Define custom errors in the config. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See step 9 here to turn on retail mode.

The default MVC template has custom errors turned on.

A nie way to enable this is enabling retail mode. This will enable custom errors for EVERY site on your machine.

https://kevww.wordpress.com/tag/mvc/

Basically just go into your machine.config and set it there.
(ex c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config)

```
<system.web>  <deployment retail="true" /></system.web>
```

Also install ELMAH to capture your errors (log them) automatically as well.

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MVC

Answer (score 1):

You can set `compilition debug="false"` in web.config.

If you want this for all the websites hosted in iis, then you can set `retail mode=true` in machine.config

If you want to show a custom error page, you can override `HttpErrors` Section in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Override `OnException` method in your controllers and show whatever you want to user on error (including e.g. your custom page style etc).

For example, see http://blog.dantup.com/2009/04/aspnet-mvc-handleerror-attribute-custom.html

Comment: What if they type some nonsense route like /foo/bar/whatever/IMadeThisUp/ ? I get these errors mainly.